# Django Filter Date Range ORM Issue

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-filter

I am having a little bit of trouble figuring out where I am going wrong here. I am atempting to gather entries in a database with a date range of 15 days, and my query is not selecting the correct options.

Here is the important part of my code:

```
start = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - timedelta(days=15)
end = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
# 2019-01-27 10:26:16.235354+00:00 | 2019-02-11 10:26:16.235354+00:00
print(start, '|', end)

completed_work_orders = WorkOrders.objects.using(db_alias).filter(
    unit_id=int(resident.unit_id),
    resident_dismissed=1).filter(date_created__range=[start, end]).order_by('-date_created')
```

Which gives me:
`completed: <QuerySet [<WorkOrders: WorkOrders object (7)>]>`

Here I only select 1 row when it should be selecting 3, here are my `date_created` values for rows 7, 8, and 9, only row 7 is being selected:

**7) Selected** 2019-02-07 12:07:59.72546-08

**8) Not Selected** 2019-02-11 08:58:27.561245-08

**9) Not Selected** 2019-02-11 09:03:35.063078-08

Comment: If you did not write this several hours ago you have a timezone offset.

Comment: @Klaus D. I changed my system time back so it is in sync and the selection issues are still there. That did appear like the issue from other questions, but it didn't matter.

Comment: With Django, you should always use `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`. That way, you ensure that you will get dates which math your project's time zone, which should then match datetimes stored in the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar, this actually fixed my issue!

Comment: Excellent! I will turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you are ending up your filtered dates having a different timezone than those stored in your database.

With Django, you should always use django.utils.timezone.now() instead of datetime.now(). That way, you ensure that you will get dates which math your project's time zone, which should then match datetimes stored in the database.

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Answer (score 0):

You end date is in UTC timezone but the records in your DB are localized to your server's timezone. Depending on your server's timezone the end date of `2019-02-11 10:26:16.235354+00:00` will actually be different, for example for NY it would be `2019-02-11 05:26:16.235354+00:00`.

Remove the `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)` from both start and end date, and you should be good.

Comment: When I do this I get a naive datetime warning. This should not be the issue. `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField WorkOrders.date_created received a naive datetime (2019-01-27 14:13:50.546234) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)`